# a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to use Spring Boot Security in my project by creating a simple login screen but i get these error even i define a bean for BCryptPassworrdEncoder. The full error is

> ***Field bCryptPasswordEncoder in
>   com.mahmut.demoemployee.application.dao.Imp.UserDaoImp required a bean
>   of type
>   'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'
>   that could not be found.***

Here is my codes.

```
package com.mahmut.demoemployee.application.dao.Imp;
    //Some imports

            @Component
        public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao {

            @Autowired
            UserRepository userRepository;

            @Qualifier("roleRepository")
            @Autowired
            RoleRepository roleRepository;

            @Autowired
            private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

            @Override
            public User save(User user) {
                user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                user.setActive(1);
                Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
                user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
                return userRepository.save(user);
            }

            @Override
            public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
                return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
            }

            @Override
            public List<User> findAll() {
                return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
            }
        }
```

And here is my config classes.

```
    package com.mahmut.demoemployee.application.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

Security Config class

```
 package com.mahmut.demoemployee.application.config;
//Lots of import here

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;



    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

What i tried is;

*I tried to use `PasswordEncoder` instead of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` gives the same error with Password Encoder.
I remove the `@Component` annotation and write `@Service` it gives same error as well.
I dont know if its necessary but here is my pom.xml file. There are only essential dependencies.*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mahmut</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-employee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-employee</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I dont know what else i could do. I checked lots of websites with similiar errors and did them but result is same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You used multiple class which extends of **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.
Set `order` on WebMvcConfig class.

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works. Also i add `@ComponentScan("my config package address")`. These two solved my problem

Comment: in my case, I didn't actually have multiple webmvcconfig class. Rather, I dont have it. Turns out I forgot to add it to my project when merging one of my modules to the main module.

Comment: In my case I had PasswordEncoder bean and  i was autowiring  BCryptPasswordEncoder. both should be the same class