# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying connect jwt token to my project and during the work I've some problems. I've followed instruction mentioned [here](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/), but i have errors. I was trying fix it with the same problem from [these guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234536/a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-crypto-bcrypt-bcryptpasswordencoder/51234787), but it didn't work for me. I guess, i'm missing something.

Could anyone please help me, thanks.

**Error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.example.demo.security.WebSecurity required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

**WebSecurity.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.appUserDetailsService = appUserDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

**AppUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public AppUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), emptyList());
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter (AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        try {
            Users creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), Users.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this @Bean to your WebSecurity config:

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Also, remove the BCryptPasswordEncoder from your constructor, including the field.

Comment: I've tried it, it gives me "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle"

Comment: see my updated answer. remove the passwordencoder from the constructor. and the field.

Comment: @MarcoBehler I have the same problem. Even though I defined a bean type of encoder, it throws the same error. Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 } How can I fix it?

Comment: @TonyBrand Call `this.passwordEncoder()` to get an instance of *BCryptPasswordEncoder* in the places where you depend on in the WebSecurity config class, instead of getting it being an attribut of the class

Answer (score 2):

add this to security package

```
   @Configuration
public class Encoder {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

it`s work for me

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you can of course use `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` at the same time.

Before if you have `@EnableWebSecurity` it is working fine. Now I notice that on my latest Spring Boot application, I should add also `Configuration` to make it working.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```