# Error: Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Service.AppUserService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

My WebSecurityConfig is:

```
package dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.Configurations;

import dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Service.AppUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //TODO: properly autorize these pages
        http.authorizeRequests()
/*
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
 */
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/adminDashboard").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**", "/home", "/about", "/pricing", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/registration", "/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

My AppUserService is:

```
package dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Service;

import dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Entitys.AppUser;
import dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Entitys.AppUserRepository;
import dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Entitys.ConfirmationToken;
import dev.guilder.SnowballCalculator.UserManagement.Service.Registration.ConfirmationTokenService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG =
            "user with email %s not found";

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException(
                                String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }

    public String signUpUser(AppUser appUser) {
        boolean userExists = appUserRepository
                .findByEmail(appUser.getEmail())
                .isPresent();

        if (userExists) {
            // TODO check of attributes are the same and
            // TODO if email not confirmed send confirmation email.

            throw new IllegalStateException("email already taken");
        }

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder
                .encode(appUser.getPassword());

        appUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        appUserRepository.save(appUser);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                appUser
        );

        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(
                confirmationToken);

//        TODO: SEND EMAIL

        return token;
    }

    public int enableAppUser(String email) {
        return appUserRepository.enableAppUser(email);
    }
}
```

If I put the solutions mention in
[Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848619/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-crypto-bcrypt-bcr) or [Error: Required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329349/error-required-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-crypto-bcrypt-bcryp)

I either get the same error or I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  webSecurityConfig defined in file [C:\Users\Guilder W. Milliner\Repositories\SC-403_SnowBallalculator_CapstoneProject\build\classes\java\main\dev\guilder\SnowballCalculator\Configurations\WebSecurityConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  appUserService defined in file [C:\Users\Guilder W. Milliner\Repositories\SC-403_SnowBallalculator_CapstoneProject\build\classes\java\main\dev\guilder\SnowballCalculator\UserManagement\Service\AppUserService.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Answer (score 2):

In you `WebSecurityConfig` remove the following line

```
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

and add

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And use the bean below

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
            new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    // using bCryptPasswordEncoder()
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
    return provider;
}
```